# Solr8.8 generation number increasing exponentially after each indexing

Tags: solr, solr8

I recently upgraded to Solr version 8.8. I am using DIH. I am not using SolrCloud. I have multiple cores whose generation number increases by 1 after indexing each time. But only 1 core increases generation number exponentially. I don't know how. e.g. After indexing only 3 times, the generation number was 93. All the documents are correct. Should I be concerned? Please throw some insight. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have different commit settings for that core?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you very much for the response. Somehow during merge, The autoCommit settings got uncommented. So commenting them again worked. Now generation number increased by 1.